# How can I generate a maven property that's a UUID?

Tags: maven

I have a file in my build that I want to put a UUID in every time a build is ran. I use maven's @my.property@ to do this for other properties like project.version. What's the simplest way to have maven insert a universal unique identifier (UUID) similar to java.util.UUID does? (I'd rather not write a plugin if I can avoid it)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Actually, the buildNumber is not random per build but rather the git commit hash of the build. Coincidentally, I also needed this so it's helpful, but does not answer the question.

---

It appears the 'buildNumber' property does what I need. I'm going forward with that.

Maven property:

```
[echoproperties] buildNumber=fb08b44b310c489f5b170842d3aac3c5eb5a6f7b
```

In my file:

```
    "uid": "fb08b44b310c489f5b170842d3aac3c5eb5a6f7b",
```

I used this plugin that prints all available properties (careful as some might differ - like env.* - between environments:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property environment="env" />
                            <echoproperties />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

https://florianlr.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/16/